# Mysql self join not giving accurate data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, self-join

I have employee table like below.

```
emp_id      emp_name            emp_supv
4081        Nancy Brown         0
4083        Peter Parker        4081
4055        Jacob Miller        4083
4058        Mary Ray            4083
4060        Jane Smith          4081
4061        Bob Hunter          4081
4066        Nancy Smith         0
4061        Bob Smith           4066
```

I want LIKE query with key word `Nancy` and it should return result like below(parent record with name like Nancy and it's children records.).

```
4081        Nancy Brown       0
4083        Peter Parker      4081
4060        Jane Smith        4081
4061        Bob Hunter        4081
4066        Nancy Smith       0
4061        Bob Smith         4066
```

try with following query but it is return only child records not the parent record having `emp_supv` `0`

```
SELECT sa.id AS id,sa.name AS Name,
sa2.id AS child_id, sa2.name AS child_name
FROM employees AS sa LEFT OUTER JOIN employees AS sa2
ON sa.emp_supv = sa2.emp_id where sa2.emp_name LIKE '%Nancy%';
```

Comment: `where sa2.emp_name LIKE '%Nancy%' or (sa.emp_supv is null and sa.emp_name LIKE '%Nancy%')` or `where ifnull(sa2.emp_name, sa.emp_name) LIKE '%Nancy%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with if null on join as

```
    SELECT sa.emp_id AS id,sa.emp_name AS Name, 
    sa.emp_supv AS child_id, sa2.emp_name AS child_name
    FROM Employees  AS sa 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees AS sa2
    ON case when ifnull(sa.emp_supv,0)=0 then sa.emp_id else sa.emp_supv end= sa2.emp_id 
where sa2.emp_name LIKE '%Nancy%'
```

Comment: Thanks , it is working if parent's `emp_supv` is `NULL` but what if it is 0, see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I hopte this will help you out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM employee AS a
JOIN employee AS b
ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
WHERE a.emp_name LIKE '%nancy%' OR a.emp_supv IN (SELECT emp_id FROM employee WHERE emp_name LIKE '%nancy%')
```